# Can not convert type float into UnityEngine.Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is on line 26. Just cant get it right. Help me please. I am creating a first person game and cant pass this ground check Issue.
`velocity = -2f`

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;

    public Transform groundCheak;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheak.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity = -2f;
        }


        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);


        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `velocity.y = -2f;` unless `Vector3` are immutable in Unity (I don't know).

Comment: @ja72 They're `struct`s, so not immutable (though things like `transform.position.y` isn't directly modifiable, because `transform.position` is a property: the struct changes, but doesn't get automatically assigned back to the position field).

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign `float` directly to a `Vector3`. As the name suggests `Vector3` has 3 element. So you can do:

```
velocity = new Vector3(-2f, 0, 0);
```

Or

```
velocity = new Vector3(-2f, -2f, -2f);
```

Which has different meaning.

You can check out [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/convert-a-float-to-vector3.474610/) or [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/364420/cannot-convert-float-to-unityenginevector3-how-to.html) which might be what you actually want to do.